# How to automatically delete rows that don't match a specific value in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to delete rows that don't match a specific value.

My current formula for identifying rows that don't match is
`=IF(K3<>L3,"No match","")`

This is stored in column "M" of my worksheet entitled Report One.

How do I get Excel to delete the rows automatically where value = "No Match" in column M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you genuinely want to delete the rows **automatically** whenever a cell value in column M changes to "*No match*", then you'll need a `Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()` solution.  The following code should give you what you want. It assumes your data starts on row 2.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
On Error GoTo GetOut
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim LastRow As Long, c As Range
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Row

For Each c In Sheets("Report One").Range("M2:M" & LastRow)    
    If c.Value = "No match" Then
        c.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next c

Continue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
GetOut:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Continue

End Sub
```

Comment: That is a beautiful piece of code, thanks it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the rows and see if the value is "No match" using VBA.

```
Sub DeleteNoMatch()
    LR = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row ' last row  

    for r = LR to 1 step -1 ' adjust the 1 to what row to start at. (header on the table?)
        if range("M" & r).value = "No match" then Range(r & ":" & r).EntireRow.Delete
    next r
end sub
```

You may want to change the column "M" in the LR row to something else.
If you have a table with 100 lines of data but the column M extends to row 1000 then 900 lines (at least) will be deleted.

Either you change your formula to not give no match when it's empty or change what column to determin the column to "count"

Comment: Thanks for that. I adjusted 1 to 2, as I am starting with the second row. However the code isn't compiling I am getting "Invalid outside procedure". Tried to add Sub at the start and Sub End at the end, but doesn't seem to work. What am I missing?